# CORS error when sending get reuqest from angular 6 app to elasticsearch, even when its allowed

Tags: node.js, angular, elasticsearch, cors

I have an angular 6 app that sends http requests to elasticsearch DB.

The angular app, nodejs server (that serves the angular app) and elasticsearch are hosted on the same machine, and the browser is on a different machine. The client points to the nodejs IP address using the browser.

The requests are being sent with httpClient from angular (not using any nodejs or expressjs software), and without allowing CORS request with third party package (Chrome and Firefox) or by changing the browser settings (IE 11) the browser doesn't allow the request to go out, and gives me CORS errors.

I want things to work without any adjustments, so I added the following configuration to elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length"
```

And just in case I added the following lines to my nodejs server:

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

The request is sent via service in the angular app, and its simple:

```
  getIndecies(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.full_elastic_url}/_cat/indices?format=json`)
  }
```

When I don't enable CORS with chrome/firefox/IE11 I get this message when the request is sent:

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

IE:
[image]

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I'm enabling CORS in every place that online answers recommended in order to solve this issue, but still - the browser blocks my reuqest.

Why can't I bypass this error?

How can applications, such as kibana, do this without any problem, but my angular app canno't?

Does anyone here has a magic solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same issue with my react app.  I used this [this](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). You can refer [Github](https://github.com/kinny94/Infobase) , to see how I used it.

Comment: You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your elastic config and nodejs.

Comment: @MikeTung I did that. Please read the post

Answer (score 0):

Some networks, browsers also block cors by default, in my experience the best way around this is to proxy your request through your node server.